# Android HttpClient and ThreadSafeClientConnManager Performance

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am troubleshooting a long response time after calling `HttpClient.execute(...)` and I would like to make sure I have done everything on the client to optimize HTTP requests for performance.

Requests to the network are taking anywhere from 1 to 40 seconds, but averaging around 4 seconds. I do not see network connectivity being a bottleneck because I am on a strong WiFi connection and have no issues with speed there.

The HttpClient is being set up as follows:

```
public static final int MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTION = 20;
public static final int MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE = 20;
public static final int TIMEOUT_CONNECT = 15000;
public static final int TIMEOUT_READ = 15000;

SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));

HttpParams connManagerParams = new BasicHttpParams();
ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(connManagerParams, MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS);
ConnManagerParams.setMaxConnectionsPerRoute(connManagerParams, new ConnPerRouteBean(MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE));

HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(connManagerParams, TIMEOUT_CONNECT);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(connManagerParams, TIMEOUT_READ);

ThreadSafeClientConnManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(new BasicHttpParams(), schemeRegistry);
sHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, connManagerParams);
```

Now for the subjective question: **Is there a more optimal way to set this up?**

I am wrapping the call to `HttpClient.execute(...)` with time captures, so everything underneath the call to `execute(...)` is where the average of 4+ seconds is spent.

Comment: run wireshark/shark wire and tell us whats going on with the request from there.

Comment: Also try setting TcpNoDelay on your connection params.

Comment: Possibly also set HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(httpClient.getParams(), true);

Comment: How but from emulator? What is the speed on emulator with internet connection? ie not over wifi?

Comment: Sorry Tanner, why you use sHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, null) instead of sHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, connManagerParams) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this a while back, but I'll post what was found as the problem/solution as others may find there way here.

Originally I assumed that a request would be executed immediately once it made its way into `HttpClient.execute(...)`. This was not true in my case because I was using connection pooling, which re-uses connections on the same route. Furthermore the client was configured to use 2 connections per route. It turns out that one of my blocks of code was failing to parse an API response and did not ensure the connection would get closed. As the app continued on, multiple data streams were being left open and blocked other pending connections. This limited throughput caused the erroneous behavior I was experiencing.

Using something like `EntityUtils.toString(entity)` became a better way to consume content and guarantee the connection is closed when finished.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpClient.getParams(), true);
```

Run free wireshark/sharkwire and tell us what you see.

http://www.wireshark.org/

This will tell you where the time is being spent.

Comment: there is a mobile client sharkwire or something. Save off the log file than you can read it using wireshark.

Comment: I am still waiting to be able to test this more properly -- I will mark this as correct or provide additional feedback when finished.